# Invite friends from Facebook who already exists in the user system

Tags: php, facebook

In the past days I've been reading the Facebook documentation. What I can't get to work is how to make a working script so users can invite their Facebook friends, as friends in my system, who are already registered on my site, via my social connection script made with the Facebook SDK. I would love to give you guys some code to work with, but I need to be honest: can't figure out in any way to make this work. My next step was to search on Google and GitHub. I did find something similar, but not *that* good. So currently my last hope now is some IT-guru on Stackoverflow. Ideas, tips and links would be very helpful.

Edit:

My intention is to use e-mail to make it work.

---

If you don't understand the question or have some questions - feel free to ask.

Regards.

Comment: This might be too broad, perhaps you should try http://programmers.stackexchange.com if you don't get an answer.

Comment: @span will consider it:) Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You should do this based on Facebook user id, not email.

Save the FB user id to your database, and when a new user registers on your site, pull their friend’s ids from Facebook and compare them to the ids in your database.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via `email address`.

Users in your website using their email address and Users of facebook also uses their email address.

You can check if someone invite his friends from facebook. than script check email address available or not in your database. you can show available users via his/her email.

Comment: That's my intention, but not a complete answer to my question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You won’t get the user’s friends email addresses, if they are not already users of your app.

Comment: So you will have to get email permission from them first, and also hope that they did not revoke that permission in the mean time … pretty unsafe, if you ask me – I would go with their FB id, as said in my other post.

Answer (score 0):

You may get the code from here,
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/,where you can use the 'to' field for selecting your friends to invite.

Comment: It looks like it's made for inviting to a web site? I need the possibility of invite friends from Facebook that are already members on my web site. If i can choose recipients that specific as written above, it may help. Could you explain? Thanks anyway:)

Comment: where do you want to invite your friends?

Comment: scenario: I'm a new user. I don't have any friends. But I can connect with Facebook too see which of my Facebook friends that are connected with the site before me. Now I can invite them to be my friends in the system. Please differentiate between Facebook friends and friends in my system.